# MeteorJs doesn't add data to collection - I'm stuck at point 8 of Intermediate Meteor Tutorial

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

I was studying MeteorJs this days, but stuck at this point: [Intermediate Meteor Tutorial #8 - Insert Permissions, Publishing & Meteor Toys](https://youtu.be/kCn_AnU91Dg?t=6m24s).

[image: Screenshot with error message]

```
errorClass {error: 404, reason: "Method '/recipes/insert' not found", details: undefined, message: "Method '/recipes/insert' not found [404]", errorType: "Meteor.Error"…}
```

I checked all the code. I tried to combine some ideas with "todos" tutorial. I even added insecure and autopublish packages - but error still appears.

How you can see on Screenshot in Mongol-panel there are Recipes collection. But when I type in mongo shell : show collections, it shows only "Users" collection.

I liked beginning of this tutorial and I hope, I can finish it , please help me to fix this error.

Comment: Do you have a method called `/recipes/insert`?

Comment: No, and how can method be called with this name? In this tutorial there is no methods , but i copied it from other , newer tutorial "todos" , and it did't work and i deleted it, and turn all like in current tutorial. In this code there are this for allowing publication : 
`Recipes.allow({
    insert: function(userId, doc){
        return !!userId; 
    }
})`
Also there are publish and subscribe for recipe .

Comment: Ah, I think `/recipes/insert` is a built-in Meteor method. Are you executing `const recipes = new Mongo.Collection('recipes')` on *both* the client and the server?

Comment: I think no. In this tutorial there are no "imports " like in "todos tutorial" , and I suppose, from those times (in 2015 it was posted), changed structure of project and now this code from video lessons doesn't work in new structure? And I haven't enough knowledge to fix this gap ....

Comment: Create `/lib/recipes.js` and just have the line `const recipes = new Mongo.Collection('recipes')` in it

Comment: it fires an error: Uncaught Error: There is already a collection named "recipes"
I tried to add to /lib/recipes.js  `import { Recipes } from '../client/collections/Recipes.js'; ` but app crashes : `Error: Cannot find module '../client/collections/Recipes.js'` 
but I did in /client/collections/Recipes : 
`export const Recipes = new Mongo.Collection("recipes");`

Answer (score 1):

That is one way to do it, the other is

You add

```
this.Recipes = new Mongo.Collection('Recipes')
```

to a none client or server file.

This automatically lets you access the Recipes collection to the entire proyect.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by moving client/collections/Recipe.js to import/ folder. I've added file /lib/recipes.js with one line of code: 
`import {Recipes} from '../import/Recipes.js'`
And how I see, now all works. Clicking on Submit button adds entry to MongoDB.